# Не понятно как работает маска в _mm_dp_ps и немного математики

Tags: c++, математика, sse

Есть следующий код:

```
    float SquareMag2(__m128 a,__m128 b)
    {return _mm_cvtss_f32( _mm_dp_ps( a, b, 0x3F ) );}

    float SquareMag3(__m128 a,__m128 b)
    {return _mm_cvtss_f32( _mm_dp_ps( a, b, 0x7F ) );}

    float SquareMag4(__m128 a,__m128 b)
    {return _mm_cvtss_f32( _mm_dp_ps( a, b, 0xFF ) );}
```

Не понимаю что значит маска в 3ем аргументе функции `_mm_dp_ps`.Точнее что она именно тут делает и для чего нам нужна. В описание этой функции ([Чекал тут](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/)) написано для функции `_mm_dp_ps`:

> Conditionally multiply the packed single-precision (32-bit) floating-point elements in a and b using the high 4 bits in imm8, sum the four products, and conditionally store the sum in dst using the low 4 bits of imm8.

Или же как говорим мой переводчик:

> Условно умножьте упакованные элементы с плавающей запятой одинарной точности (32-битные) в a и b, используя старшие 4 бита в imm8, просуммируйте четыре произведения и условно сохраните сумму в dst, используя младшие 4 бита imm8.

И от этого мне понятней конечно же не стало.
Понятно только то,что я пытаюсь найти скалярное произведение векторов с помощью `_mm_dp_ps`,перевожу это в тип `float` функцией `_mm_cvtss_f32`,но маску эту не понимаю,для чего и что даёт.

Могу порассуждать что типо:
Есть какие-то векторы

```
__m128 a{1,2,3,4};
__m128 b{4,3,2,1};
```

Их скалярное произведение равно `1*4+2*3+3*2+4*1=20`

`20` я получу если буду использовать функцию `SquareMag4`ведь маска внутри этой функции `FF` или `1111.1111` (*Главное что в названии есть 4,т.е. логично же что 4бита в первом значении F*) и путём подстановки разных значений вектора,ответ всегда верный. т.е. наличие байта из всех `8` единиц даёт мне всегда правильное число.

`16` я получу в случае если использую `SquareMag3` (*И тут цифра в названии `SquareMag3` подтверждает мою теорию о количестве бит*) маска внутри `7F` т.е. `0111.1111` первые `3` бита

**У меня 2 вопроса**:

- **1** как работает эта маска? просто если взять `SquareMag3`, можно было бы сказать что `7F` это `0111.1111` или число `127` и оно меньше чем полученное скалярное произведение и по этому дало `16`,*но это не так*.
- **2** мне понятно для чего можно использовать скалярное произведение векторов функции `SquareMag4`, а для чего другие? зачем это урезание? Может кто-то подскажет)

*Очень прошу писать простым языком и с объяснением,думаю ответ на то и ответ,что бы он объяснял,а не был очередной загадкой*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я в таких случаях смотрю в пример псевдокода, который часто приводится рядом. И из него следует следующее.

В регистрах у нас хранятся два массива по 4 элемента. И 4 бита маски им однозначно соответствуют. Эти элементы попарно перемножаются, а потом суммируются, но только те, где в маске в левой половине стоят единицы. То есть, если старшие 4 бита единицы, то будут попарно перемножены все элементы и просуммированы. Если там нули, то результат будет нулевой. Если там только 0001, то результат будет равен произведению последних элементов с каждого массива.

Ок, сумма произведения у нас есть. Теперь идем к второй половине квеста. Тут в игру вступают младшие 4 бита. Они определяют, куда будет скопирован результат. Если там 1111, то результат будет скопирован во все 4 "элемента массива" регистра. Если же там 0011 (то есть 0х03), то результат будет скопирован только в два элемента. В те регистры, которым соответствуют нули, будет скопирован 0 (судя по коду)

В конце концов к результату функции применяется _mm_cvtss_f32, которая берет самый младший "элемент массива" и возвращает его как результат.

Так как функция _mm_cvtss_f32 копирует только один элемент массива, то нам все равно, какая маска находится в правой половине, главное, что бы она была "нечетной", то есть 0х01, 0х03 .. 0хD, 0x0F - все 8 вариантов подходят и результат не поменяется.

Теперь пойдем по функциям

```
SquareMag4 = a[3]*b[3]+a[2]*b[2]+a[1]*b[1]+a[0]*b[0];
SquareMag3 = a[2]*b[2]+a[1]*b[1]+a[0]*b[0];
SquareMag2 = a[1]*b[1]+a[0]*b[0];
```

(если только я не ошибся с направлением право-лево), то это легко можно проверить, умножив `{1,2,3,4}` и `{1,1,1,1}`

Функции SquareMag1 нет, потому что это просто перемножить два числа и тут компилятор сам управится не хуже.

Зачем нужны такие функции? Да очень просто. К примеру, SquareMag3  нужна для работы с трехмерными векторами. Да, можно старший элемент держать равным нулю, а можно просто использовать такую функцию.

Вариант номер два - представьте, что Вы хотите это сделать для вектора размерности 10 (а почему бы и нет?). И тут легко разбивается на три вектора - два по 4 и один на два. Для каждого применяется функция, а потом суммируется. И это будет достаточно быстро.

Comment: Сложно,не понимаю,раз 10 прочитал всё равно не идёт.  Начиная со 2ого абзаца Вы можете мне разжевать чутка подробнее? лучше в виде примера и попроще чуть-чуть,пожалуйста

Comment: А нет,всё,на 20ый раз допёр,не надо разжёвывать Х)

Comment: то, что mmx/sse регистр - это просто массив? я понимаю, это сложно, но один раз доходит и потом уже все ок. Но можно смотреть на это ещё шире. регистр - это просто кусок памяти, а то, как мы его интерпретируем, зависит от команды. то есть, 128 бит это может быть 4 32битных целых или 4 float, или 8 16битных без знака или даже 16 байт (8 битных).